# Error tests Codeception PhpStorm and Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, codeception

I'm new to testing and I'm doing the test setup with Codeception, PHP, Docker in PhpStorm.

I am having an error when I run my tests. It appears to be something in the phpstorm_helpers container that is created by the IDE at run time.

Follow the error below and my settings.

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/src/myapp/vendor/bin/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/codeception.php on line 30
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You sponged out the path, so just to be sure - it's a `:` that you have in front of `/usr/src/myapp` in the `Docker container` field? If so, try using a different image, `phpstorm/php-cli:latest`, for instance. Any better with it?

Comment: If you'd set up your PHP Interpreter correct in the IDE then you should not have any issues.